# CalendarView Issues when Used Directly (Outside of a DatePicker)

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I'm using a `CalendarView` directly, not a `DatePicker`, b/c its being used as a drop-down/pop-up style dialog where space is factor ( the user clicks a button located to the right of date field, and the `CalendarView` drops down, appearing directly below the field, aligned/anchored to the button).

There are **two show-stopping issues** I've ran into, and spent an entire 10 hour day debugging with no resolve.

**Issue #1 - Weeks Missing**

Weeks appear to missing, and depending on the date, sometimes the week missing will correspond to the "default"/current date (the date the displayed record contains that was loaded from the DB), and so when I display the `CalendarView`, and call setDate() to auto-select it, no date will appear to be selected (although the `CalendarView` will be centered around the missing week).

[image]

The way I've been fixing this is to manually scroll down, and then back up a few months, and the refresh usually fixes the display. However, I haven't found a way to automate this scrolling, which could be a potential work around.  I tried calling `setDate()` in succession to do this, but it seems to only work on the first call, which brings me to my next issue.

**Issue #2 - `setDate()` Auto-Scrolling Not Working**

It seems that only the first call to `setDate()` will cause the `CalendarView` to be centered around the corresponding date. If I choose a new date (and store it in private member) and dismiss the popup, and then bring it back up with another dropdown-button click, which will now call `setDate()` with this new date, then the `CalendarView` will be centered around the old/previous date, even though the new date is actually hilited (which can be confirmed my manually scrolling down to it).

I can attach code if required, but before spending the time to do so, I just wanted to see if this is a well known issue.

Thank you.

Comment: ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17518677/android-calendarview-drops-weeks-at-random

Comment: **note** for the time being, if anyone else is having this issue, just use a date-spinner instead (someone I work with gave me the idea, and he doesn't even program!!).

Answer (score 0):

**This is just a work-around (also, I've been working in Monodroid/C#, not raw Android)**

By first calling SetDate() with a value for the last day of the month previous to the desired display date, and then calling it with the desired date, it seems to work consistently as expected (make sure this date falls between the Max/Min dates of the CalendarView).

However, the second call needs to be posted as a runnable to the UI thread.

Here is some code (note the boolean flags to SetDate, for centering and scroll-animation, neither of which work, hence this work-around):

```
View view = _inflater.Inflate( Resource.Layout.CalendarViewPicker, null );

CalendarView cvPicker = view.FindViewById<Android.Widget.CalendarView>( Resource.Id.cv_picker );

DateTime lastDay = new DateTime(_date.Year, _date.Month, 1).AddDays(-1);
long lastDayTicks = Ticks( lastDay.Date );

cvPicker.SetDate( lastDayTicks, true, true );
cvPicker.Post( () => {cvPicker.SetDate(Ticks(_date.Date),true,true)} );
```

Passing _date.Date to Ticks() passes a DateTime with a Time of 12:00am (basically "zeros out" time element), as opposed to passing just _date, which is also a DateTime.  Also, a conversion function is needed, since I'm using C#/.NET, to convert the tick-offset

```
private long Ticks( DateTime date )
{  
   DateTime _1970 = (new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).AddDays(-1);

   return (date.Ticks - _1970.Ticks) / 10000;
}
```

**Resource.Layout.CalendarViewPicker.axml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="@dimen/calendar_view_width"
  android:layout_height="@dimen/calendar_view_height"
  android:background="#FF666666">

  <Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_picker_exit"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="36dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@drawable/cv_button_background"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:text="+"/>

  <CalendarView
    android:id="@+id/cv_picker"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/calendar_view_width"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/calendar_view_height"
    android:shownWeekCount="6"/>

<RelativeLayout/>
```

My reasoning for the first call to SetDate() with the last day of the previous month, was b/c many times the calendar would popup with the second week of a given month showing as the first visible week, and when scrolling up to see the first week, I would find it missing. So, I figured setting the date with the last day of the previous month might force the first week (ie, the problematic week) to show.

Now with the first week showing, I call SetDate again, but it only works when posted, b/c when posting a runnable to the UI, the event is scheduled to occur after the associated view is rendered. If 2 SetDate()'s are called consecutively (neither in a runnable), say in OnCreate(), then the effects take place before the view is rendered, and so only the second call would take effect, overwriting the first (and therefore loosing the effect of forcing the first week to show).

These two calls also fix the centering/auto-scrolling issue, which is nice too.